# How to add an image and erase table border?

Tags: tables, multicolumn

Please help me prepare resume

Basically, 
Dividing the res document into 2 mini pages of width .7 and .3

Within .7 line width minipage,
creating 3 columns 
1st columns runs all the way until the end of the page 
but 2 and 3 runs every 4 rows as shown below
2nd column contains the description of the projects undertaken
3rd column contains year and company logos

Also, not sure how to add tick mark as bullet points.
[image: resume_latex]

How can we 
1. remove borders of the table
2. add disproportionate images into the table ?
inserting attachment_1 image in "value 1" column 
instead of row 3 and 4 ?
[image: attachment_1]

[image: current output]

```
\begin{table}[h!]
  \begin{center}
    \caption{Multirow and -column table.}
    \label{tab:table1}
    \begin{tabular}{l|S|r}
      \textbf{Value 1} & \textbf{Value 2} & \textbf{Value 3}\\
      $\alpha$ & $\beta$ & $\gamma$ \\
      \hline
      \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{1234}} & a\\ % <-- Multicolumn spanning 2 columns, content multirow spanning two rows
      \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & b\\ % <-- Multicolumn spanning 2 columns with empty content as placeholder
      \hline
      3 & 23.113231 & c\\
      4 & 25.113231 & d\\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: To remove the lines, remove all occurences of `|` and `\hline` from your code. If this does not give you the desired result, please clarify your question. Regarding the second part: ` add disproportionate images` in unfortunately unclear since your code fragment does not currently contain any images. What exactly is your problem with this. Please also clarify.

Comment: Please also make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages that you use. Is the `S` type column from the `cellspace` or from the `siunitx` package or a custom defined column type?

Comment: thanks for your response. 
Attached an image to demonstrate.

Basically, instead of 3,4 row in Value 1 column, can we insert that image ?

the sample is from 
https://www.latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/tables/

Comment: What 's the desired alignment of `23.11` and `25.11` with respect to the image? top, bottom or center aligned? Probably a sketch of the desired output would help. Please also add some background info on what you want to achieve with that table.

Comment: In that question, there is no row is merged. 
While in my case, first column i.e, "Value 1", all the rows are merged/combined to just insert 1 bubble image (attachment_1)

Column 2, has bulleted points (4 rows merged/combined)
Column 3, is again image i.e. logo (merges 3 rows/combined)